# Getting all valid combinations in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I think my title is not correct for this issue but since english is not my mother tongue i couldn't figure out a better way to title my problem.

So what i have is different Players with a few properties:

```
Player_one.name = "A";
Player_two.name = "B";
Player_three.name = "C";
Player_four.name = "D";
```

Players also have property:

```
Player_one.canPlay = ["B","D"];
Player_two.canPlay = ["A","D"];
Player_three.canPlay = ["A","C"];
Player_four.canPlay = ["B","D"]
//note that this is example and may not be accurate right now
```

Property canPlay shows with who player can play with.

Now players also have property called "placeInTable" which shows their current spot, for example position one, two or three etc.

What i would like to achieve is to check whether it is possible to make combinations from every canPlay array so that every player is able to play with another in the current round. In case there are several possible options, for example, if player one can play with player two and three and games still could be played with everyone then the player with higher "placeInTable" will be selected for an opponent.

To sum my idea up is that i'm trying to create a swiss system table which manages the next games properly. Algorithm should check every canPlay for each player and create combinations which would result in a way that every player is able to play with another and if several options for games are available it will choose the best opponent first according to "placeInTable".

What i've done so far is that i have an algorithm which will start checking the table from the beginning, if player can't play with another the lower one will be selected. Although my current algorithm is faulty since if the length-1 and length-2 players have played with each other the algorithm does not know what to do. So for that i'll add two upper players from which the algorithm crashes, currently length-1 and length-2 so the players length-3 and length-4 will be added and canPlay check will be ran.

I hope my description for this problem was not too misleading and could be understood and really big kudos to someone who is able to help.

If any questions i'd be happy to describe more about this issue.

Edit no. 1:

I forgot to add that in Swiss System two players can't play with each other once they've already played with each other. That's why i have canPlay and in first round the canPlay array length may be longer and in fifth or sixth it may be really small.

About answer which suggested that if A can play with B and B can play with C then A can play with C then no, it's not correct idea. Better understanding could be made with an example.

Let's say there are possible combinations like:

```
A vs B
C vs D
//and
A vs D
B vs C
```

Now in such manner every player can play with every other player but there's two options. Now if the table goes that player A has spot 1, player B spot 2, player C spot 3 and player D spot 4 then it should choose the first option because players in higher place in table should be placed together.

There could be of course a third option, player A vs player C && player B vs player D but i left it out right now. IF there would be third option then still the first one would be selected since it places the higher spots together.

Edit no. 2:

```
function reastaArray(){
var newArr = jQuery.extend(true,[],playerLst); //copy of original players
var original = jQuery.extend(true,[],playerLst);
var inPlay = []; //siia hakkame lisama
var firstRound = true;
var visitedCount = 1;
var i = 0;
var count = 0;
while (newArr.length != 0){
    //this goes on until there are players left in playerList
    count = i;
    hereiam = false;
    if (inPlay.length % 2 == 0){ //if the players in play are even amount then the first one gets pushed without a check
        inPlay.push(newArr[i]);
        newArr.splice(i,1);
    }
    else{ //now we need to search for opponent
        var lastEl = inPlay[inPlay.length-1];
        var element = newArr[i];
        var played = hasPlayed(element,lastEl); //true/false, can we play with last element in inPlay, if it's true then while cycle begins
        while (played == true){
            count += 1;
            if (count == newArr.length){ //if we've reached at the end of the newArr and still haven't found an opponent
                //take in last played games into new array
                takeLast(inPlay,newArr);
                for (var y = 0; y<visitedCount;y++){
                    takeLast(inPlay,newArr);
                    takeLast(inPlay,newArr);
                }
                canWePlayNow(newArr);
                //populize canPlay-s.

                //IDEA FROM STACK

                var combinations = findCombinations(newArr);
                console.log("possible combinations");
                combinations.forEach(function(comb) {
                console.log(comb);
                });
                console.log(findBest(combinations,newArr));
                visitedCount += 1;


            }
            else{
                element = newArr[count];
                played = hasPlayed(element,lastEl);
            }
        }
        if (hereiam == false){
        inPlay.push(element);
        newArr.splice(count,1);
        }


    }
}
return inPlay;
}

function canWePlayNow(newArr){
for (var i = 0; i<newArr.length;i++){
    var player = newArr[i];
    player.canPlay = [];
    var hasPlayed = player.playedNames;
    for (var j = i+1; j<newArr.length;j++){
        playerFromPlayed = newArr[j];
        var inArr = isInArray(hasPlayed,playerFromPlayed.name);
        if (inArr == false){
            player.canPlay.push(playerFromPlayed.name);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The combination array could work better, right now as i tested it does:

[image]

As seen from image, first round is calculated great, now second round values are entered and third round calculation messes up: It could put together 5vs6 ; 1vs4 and 2vs3, but this algorithm you provided is pretty close already, could you give a further look to check out what's wrong?

Edit no 3:

With further inspection it seems like it's still doing something wrong. As seen from image below the correct result should be 1 & 2 and 5 vs 3 although next games shown are 1vs5 & 3vs2, which shouldn't be result.

The input for the array were Players who've had already one round of free or as in table "V". The algorithm you posted is unchanged.

As seen from console, the other option which i pointed out above is in combinations but it's not selected. Any ideas?

[image]

Edit no 4:

Added new image!

```
function findBest(combinations, players) {
  if(combinations.length === 0) throw new Error();
  var koht = {};
  function score(comb) {
    return comb.reduce(function(score, pair) {
      //console.log("New calc:");
      //console.log(score+koht[pair[0]]*koht[pair[1]]);
      return score + koht[pair[0]] * koht[pair[1]];
    }, 0);
  };
  players.forEach(function(p) {
    koht[p.name] = p.koht;
  });
  var best = combinations[0];
  combinations.slice(1).forEach(function(comb) {
    console.log(score(comb) + " = combs & best = "+score(best));
    console.log("Checked combs: ");
    console.log(comb);
    if(score(comb) > score(best)) {
        best = comb;
    }
  });
  console.log("Returned array: (best)");
  console.log(best);
  return best;
}
```

[image]

Added Log to KOHT

[image]

Comment: I changed my answer. Try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that displays all possible combinations in which each player gets to play. It then tries to find the best one by preferring pairings of players in high spots.

```
function findCombinations(players) {
  var combinations = [];

  function removePlayer(a, name) {
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if(a[i].name === name) return a.slice(0, i).concat(a.slice(i+1));
    }
    return a;
  }

  function find(players, comb) {
    if(players.length === 0) {
      combinations.push(comb);
      return;
    };
    var player = players[0];
    player.canPlay.forEach(function(other) {
      var newPlayers = removePlayer(players, other);
      if(newPlayers !== players && other !== player.name) {
        find(newPlayers.slice(1), comb.concat([[player.name, other]]));
      }
    });
  }

  find(players, []);
  return combinations;
}

function findBest(combinations, players) {
  if(combinations.length === 0) throw new Error();
  var placeInTable = {};
  function score(comb) {
    return comb.reduce(function(score, pair) {
      return score + placeInTable[pair[0]] * placeInTable[pair[1]];
    }, 0);
  };
  players.forEach(function(p) {
    placeInTable[p.name] = p.placeInTable;
  });
  var best = combinations[0];
  combinations.slice(1).forEach(function(comb) {
    if(score(comb) > score(best)) best = comb;
  });
  return best;
}

var p1 = {name: "A", canPlay: ["B", "D", "C"], placeInTable: 1},
    p2 = {name: "B", canPlay: ["A", "D"], placeInTable: 2},
    p3 = {name: "C", canPlay: ["A", "C", "D"], placeInTable: 3},
    p4 = {name: "D", canPlay: ["B", "D", "C"], placeInTable: 4};

var players = [p1, p2, p3, p4],
    combinations = findCombinations(players);

console.log("possible combinations");
combinations.forEach(function(comb) {
  console.log(comb);
});

console.log("\nbest:");
console.log(findBest(combinations, players));
```

Comment: I'm completely dazzled now, i implemented this to my code and it still does not work in a manner it should re-organize them. In a minute i will add my whole calculation function in the edit in my first so maybe it's possible for you to give some pointers.

Comment: Had to make another edit. There was still an error in my code.

Comment: Uh okay, i test with edited, i already made an edit for you in first post aswell

Comment: Okay, the edit did not change the problem described in my last edit

Comment: Edited my first post function with comments, now it should be understandable

Comment: Could you give me a list of player data for which findCombinations or findBest returns a wrong result? Also, I can't run your code. A runnable example - maybe on jsfiddle - would be helpful.

Comment: If it's not much trouble, my whole test page is in http://kevin.planet.ee/test 
In that page you will find Generator where you can enter names, enter for example six names (must be even number). Then select swiss system and you'd be refered to the table. As for values, in the second table you could enter in round one (each value in each box) 1:0 , 1:0 , 1:1. Then you click "Järjesta" (Which is arrange in Estonian). Then in second round you can enter: 1:0 , 1:1 and 1:0 for example. Now you can see that they could be lined more suitable. (Näita ajalugu button shows history of last games)

Comment: However, if you are completely sure that your function will always work for sure then it might be an issue in my function and maybe i should rethink the way i'm doing it right now.

Comment: In this case, if you're completely sure i think your algorithm could be set to the whole playerList array just my canWePlayNow() function should be called out before your algorithm to populize canPlay arrays.

Comment: Okay, @SpiderPig i got an idea what might be wrong. canPlay does not contain Players as objects but players with player names. This is because if i want to deepcopy my playerList i won't be sent into recurssive loop.

Comment: In your code you are calling findCombinations and findBest but you are not using the results that those functions return. It can't work if you are not using it.

Comment: Hey @SpiderPig i found a bug i guess, edited the top comment. Any ideas? I can't figure out your function findBest which seems to create this bug right now

Comment: Looking at the image it seems that player 4 is at place 1 in the table, player 1 is at place 2, player 2 is at 3, player 5 is at 4 and player 3 is at place 5. findBest will calculate a score for each combination. for 1&2 vs 3&5 the score would be 2*3 + 5*4 = 26, for 1&5 vs 2&3 the score is 2*4 + 3*5 = 23. That means that 1&2 vs 3&5 should be picked. If it picks the other one, check what the values of placeInTable are and what findBest returns.

Comment: Added new image & added .log-s in code aswell. As you can see i changed placeInTable to koht just to fit in my language, nothing else changed but the variable name.

Comment: Can you also log players and koht? It looks like koht contains wrong values.

Comment: Added, it sure seems that there's wrong values, doesen't it? Why would it be like this, although they're correct in table

Comment: Dude, hold the phone for a second, i think i've got it figured out, totally my bug which i did not see, reporting back after a bit

Comment: Okay, what was wrong was i created an array which to hold players who have been in free round already and added them in that. Then i tried to find combinations but forgot to update their placeInTable or "koht" aswell. After updating these, everything's smooth, thanks for taking another step towards my project complition.